# angular2 : Reusing common component twice on the same page

Tags: typescript, angular2-components

How would be able reuse one component twice with different model on the same page, if it would be different slides?

**Example:**

```html
<component [(model)]="model1"></component>
<component [(model)]="model2"></component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my solution were problem with not unique ids of radioGroup's elements
if use twice component you have to remember that elements in different radioGroup's  have ti have different id's other way you have deadlock of model on the 2nd, 3rd, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ngFor.
ts file:

```
var models = [model1, model2];
```

Html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let mod of models">
      <component [(model)]="mod"></component>
   </div>
```

Comment: i can't use this case, because they must be on different slides of app (((
i need use them separatly